# docker container can't use `service sshd restart`

Tags: docker, ssh, dockerfile, sshd

I am trying to build a hadoop `Dockerfile`.

In the build process, I added:

```
  && apt install -y openssh-client \
  && apt install -y openssh-server \
  && ssh-keygen -t rsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa \
  && cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys \
  && chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
  && sed -i '/\#AuthorizedKeysFile/ d' /etc/ssh/sshd_config \
  && echo "AuthorizedKeysFile ~/.ssh/authorized_keys" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config \
  && /etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

I assumed that when I ran this container:

```
docker run -it --rm hadoop/tag bash
```

I would be able to:

```
ssh localhost
```

But I got an error:

> ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused

If I run this manually inside the container:

```
/etc/init.d/ssh restart
# or this
service ssh restart
```

Then I can get connected. I am thinking that this means *the sshd restart didn't work*.

I am using `FROM java` in the `Dockerfile`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The build process only builds an image. Processes that are run at that time (using `RUN`) are no longer running after the build, and are not started again when a container is launched using the image.

What you need to do is get sshd to start *at container runtime*. The simplest way to do that is using an entrypoint script.

**Dockerfile:**

```
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["whatever", "your", "command", "is"]
```

**entrypoint.sh:**

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# Start the ssh server
/etc/init.d/ssh restart

# Execute the CMD
exec "$@"
```

Rebuild the image using the above, and when you use it to start a container, it should start sshd before running your `CMD`.

You can also change the base image you start from to something like [Phusion baseimage](http://phusion.github.io/baseimage-docker/) if you prefer. It makes it easy to start some services like syslogd, sshd, that you may wish the container to have running.

Comment: Thanks, Mr Lowe. This really helped. and I saw the modification on my question context. Thanks again and i bet you must do a lot this kind of grammar correction daily to your daughter? I am not a native english-speaker, sorry for that.

Comment: @cinqS I did clean up the post a little bit - just standard procedure around here... didn't mean any offense, to be clear... we have a lot of non-native English speakers, so those of us who are native speakers do our best to help the posts be as readable as they can be.